# Unable to ravel a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array
`x = np.array([145100, [ 1,2,3  ], 100.6])`
and I wish to ravel it to this:
`[145100,  1,2,3 , 100.6]`

I tried this, but it didn't gave any results:

```
x = np.ravel(x)
```

As the shape was still (3,) instead of (5,). What am I missing?

Comment: With (3,) shape, it is 'raveled'.  It is already 1d.  When you made this did you get a "ragged array" warning?

Comment: nope (used Jupyter lab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([145100, [ 1,2,3 ], 100.6])
x = np.hstack(x)
```

```
array([1.451e+05, 1.000e+00, 2.000e+00, 3.000e+00, 1.006e+02])
```